# Using Button Label value as title of another window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So currently teaching myself Python and Tkinter and was wondering if you can take the text label value of a button and use it to label a window in another .py that the button on the initial .py calls.

If thats as clear as mud try this (lol):
I currently have two .py files (i know i could have labelled them better but i wasn't expecting it to evolve this far):

main.py (connects to an AWS sql database)

main_app_page.py

I have a button on main_app_page labelled Button1 and if you click it, it loads main.py.  I would like the label of Button1 to be the .title value of main.py.

Code I have currently
main_app_page.py

```
def acstatus():
    os.system('python main.py')

button = Button(main_page, text="Button1", width=10, command=acstatus)
```

main.py

```
ac_status = Tk()
ac_status.title(' ')
ac_status.geometry("500x700")
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can technically do it this way:**

*main_app_page.py*

```py
def acstatus():
    os.system('python main.py Title')


button = Button(main_page, text="Button1", width=10, command=acstatus)
```

*main.py*

```py
import sys
...

title = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else "Alternate title"
ac_status.title(title)
```

**However, a much better approach would be to use `import` statement in a similar way as this (define a function that you call from the module that imports the module that defines that function), though you should learn more about `import`s:**

*main_app_page.py*

```py
import main


def acstatus():
    main.main("Title")


button = Button(main_page, text="Button1", width=10, command=acstatus)
```

*main.py*

```py
import tkinter as tk
...


def main(title):
    ac_status = tk.Tk()
    ac_status.title(title)
```

---

Also, just in case:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Matiss, I think it may work but i'm getting an error back: RuntimeError: Too early to create variable: no default root window.  Which i've not had before